# Binary Expression Tree

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

i'm very new in haskell and i have a problem. I want to take list for ex. [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1] and put the elements in a Tree structure which is;

`data Tree = Leaf Int | Node String (Tree) (Tree)`

so far wrote the below code but it gives an error.

```
bdd (x:xs)= if elem x [0..9] then Leaf x else Node x (Tree) (Tree)
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: What does your function `bdd` try to accomplish ? And what error does it give.

Comment: in that tree there will be nodes which are string and the bottom leaves are the integers, so i tried to check whether it is integer or not so call the tree again but it says tree is not in scope.

Comment: What is the `Tree` resulting from `[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]` supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `Tree` constructor on the recursive call of your function, bdd should return a `Tree`, wich is build with `Leaf` or `Node`, but notice that Node should be build with 2 trees with also should be built with `Leaf` or `Node`, not `Tree`

```
bdd :: [Int] -> Tree
bdd (x:xs)= if elem x [0..9] then Leaf x else Node (show x) (bdd xs) (bdd xs)
```

You should check how you want to properly build the tree, this is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Your code tries to put `x` in a `Leaf`, requiring it to be an `Int`, and also tries to put out in a `Node`, requiring it to be a `String`. Certainly `Int` and `String` are different types, so this won't compile. Also, `Tree` is a type constructor, so you can't use it in terms. What's your code actually supposed to do?

Comment: it should take the list and element by element add them from the bottom left to bottom right, because this tree will be expression tree like f(x1,x2,x3)